# Customising Breadcrumb NavXT

Tags: breadcrumb, theme-twenty-sixteen

The plugin is working fine (thanks to them) but I'd like to customise it slightly. For example the following example trail is the default:
Home > Report > July-2016 > Article

'Article' is not linked as we are already on that post/page. I would
a) like to remove 'Article' from the trail as this is anyway the title of the post/page that sits just below the breadcrumb on my site
b) potentially (just to see how it looks) replace 'Article' with a static text such as *'> You are here'* with its own class

Clearly I could just write a rule for 'level 4' but I may have other breadcrumbs with 2 to 5 levels... Modifying with css rule `.breadcrumb a:last-child` has been unsuccessful. Any tips how to achieve? I also asked on wp forum, but they have thousands of unloved questions, it seems. I will add the solution there if we get one here.

Of-course you may a solution that requires only a change in the wp permalink structure, but I haven't managed to do that.
Many thanks, Bill

Comment: Your question is confusing.

Comment: Sorry - seems simple to me - I just don't want to see the (redundant) last entry of the breadcrumb trail - because a) I'm already on that page and b) it's not a link...

Comment: Wat plugin? What is level4?

Comment: Plugin is in title, level 4 is the 4th (last) entry of the suggested breadcrumb - Article

Comment: It seems that only one person found my question confusing. For future reference, here is the answer from the plugin developer:

Comment: For option a, see the Breadcrumb NavXT FAQ.

For option b, since there isn't an all encompassing "current item breadcrumb template", you have two options:

    Since all the unlinked breadcrumb templates are used for the current item, just replace the %title% and %htitle% tags with 'You are here'.
    Write a filter for the bcn_breadcrumb_title hook, check for the current item and programatically change it to 'You are here'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For option a, see the Breadcrumb NavXT FAQ.

For option b, since there isn't an all encompassing "current item breadcrumb template", you have two options:

```
Since all the unlinked breadcrumb templates are used for the current item, just replace the %title% and %htitle% tags with 'You are here'.
Write a filter for the bcn_breadcrumb_title hook, check for the current item and programatically change it to 'You are here'.
```

John HavliK